# Storage for values in an array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Is it always necessary that all the values of an array will be stored sequentially.

For example if I declare INT arr[10]. So is it necessary that these values will be stored sequentially on the disk. Can values of an array be stored in random memory locations ??

Comment: For the array data structure in terms of general functionally I guess you don't have to. In the sense you can say it *acts* like an array but isn't. It doesn't make sense not to unless you are wanting to use something more dynamic like a linked-list. As it would cost more space and be slower (*index lookup would be `O(n)` rather than `O(1)`*).